# Client-server, can't figure it out how to make multiclients sending string to one server

Tags: java, server, client

need a bit of help.. Creating a project client-server to make it working on watching files. Everything is working,exept the part where i should get messages from client. Don't know why i do not get it.

```
package server;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException, ClassNotFoundException {
    new Config();
    new ClientComm();
    while(true){

        ClientComm.getLineAndTypeFromClient();

    }
    System.out.println(ClientComm.ois.available());
}
}
```

Client.java:

```
package client;

public class Client {


    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception{

        new Config();
        new ServerComm();
        if(ServerComm.sendAuth() == true) {
            System.out.println("Client connected to server : " + ServerComm.getSocket().isConnected());
            new FileProcessing();
        }

    }
}
```

ServerComm.java : Sending info to server from client.

```
package client;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ServerComm{

    private static Socket socket;
    private static ObjectOutputStream oos;


    public ServerComm() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        socket = new Socket(Config.getHost(), Config.getPort());
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    }

    protected static void sendLine(String line, String type) throws IOException{

        String[] a = {line,type};
        oos.writeUnshared(a);
        oos.flush();
        System.out.println(oos);
        oos.reset();
    }

    protected static Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    protected static boolean sendAuth() throws IOException {

        String project_id = Config.getProject_id();
        String user_id = Config.getUser_id();

        String[] auths = {project_id, user_id};
        oos.writeUnshared(auths);
        oos.flush();
        oos.reset();
        System.out.println(oos);
        return true;

    }   

}
```

ClientComm.java : receiving info from client.

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ClientComm{

    private static Socket client;
    private static ServerSocket server;
    public static ObjectInputStream ois;

    public ClientComm() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(Config.getPort());
            System.out.println("Server started");

            while (true)
            {
                client = server.accept();
                checkAuth();
                System.out.println("New Connection");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    protected static void getLineAndTypeFromClient() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        String[] variables = (String[]) ois.readObject();
        for(String variable : variables) {
            System.out.println(variable);
        }
        ois.reset();
    }

    private void checkAuth() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> auths = new ArrayList<String>();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String[] authArray = (String[]) ois.readObject();
        for(String auth : authArray) {
            auths.add(auth);
        }
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < auths.size() ; i++) {

            if(Config.getProjectId().equals(auths.get(i)) || Config.getUserId().equals(auths.get(i)) ){
                temp += 1;
            }
            else {
                temp -= 1;
            }

        }
        if(temp == auths.size()) {
            temp = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Auth failed");
            temp = 0;
            client.close();
        }




    }

}
```

Tell me what im doing wrong! :)

Comment: new Config(); new ClientComm(); this strings are useless. You just create anonymous objects which have no incoming references. So they will be wiped out by GC and you would never get the access to them. [UPD], sorry, what you actually do looks very tricky. you should reconsider the design of your code. Use less static and more named objects :)

Comment: Without them i cant open server socket, that's why i initialize them like that

Comment: I have a problem with object naming.. :) later i will do more study about that, atm i have a project, and these static methods and variables is what my college asked..

Comment: The main reason is about that :

ServerComm.sendLine(String line, string type) || SENDS LINE AND TYPE TO SERVER

ClientComm.getLineAndTypeFromClient(); || HAVE TO GET THE LINE AND TYPE, BUT IT DOESNT. 

This is the real question, why? :)